# How do I fix the duration of frames when using avconv?

Tags: 14.04, avconv

So far, I'm doing something like this

```
avconv -i "image%d.png" -f image2 - delay 100 -s:v 1280x720 ./filename.mpg
```

but the delay does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got the `-delay` option from; in the manpage for `avconv` I have on my system it isn't mentioned.

Try

```
avconv -i image%d.png -r 60 ./filename.mpg
```

as it wasn't the only problem with your command.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful, I hope...
To set the video bitrate of the output file to 64kbit/s:
`avconv -i input.avi -b 64k output.avi`

To force the frame rate of the output file to 24 fps:
`avconv -i input.avi -r 24 output.avi`

To force the frame rate of the input file (valid for raw formats only) to 1 fps and the frame rate of the output file to 24 fps
`avconv -r 1 -i input.m2v -r 24 output.avi`